# Angular UI Boostrap dropdown does not open with [is-open] and [append-to] attributes

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I want to use the bootstrap dropdown from the [angular ui lib](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/dropdown).

I'm getting an issue when I append the dropdown to another DOM element with `dropdown-append-to` (even `dropdown-append-to-body` is not working).

I can't have it working only when I use `is-open` with `ng-click` to trigger the dropdown.

I reproduced the issue in this [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/DiHBlyZ8c3zwOsPc56jd?p=preview).

I'm using bootstrap 3.3.6, angular ui 2.1.3 and angular 1.5.8.

Hope somebody can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should work with `uib-dropdown-toggle` and also add an `ng-click` and toggle `test` at your controller

Also, `dropdown-append-to-body` should accept a value (default is false), like so `dropdown-append-to-body="true"`

```
<div class="btn-group" uib-dropdown dropdown-append-to-body="true" is-open="test">
    <button type="button" ng-click="onClick(test)" class="btn btn-primary" uib-dropdown-toggle>
      Dropdown on Body <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" uib-dropdown-menu role="menu" aria-labelledby="btn-append-to-body">
      <!-- list items -->
    </ul>
</div>
```

[exmaple plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/4rmcO8yS1Srq2pKiOWeT?p=preview)

Comment: I did not think of using both, it does the trick. Thanks @svarog.